# Trouble invoking method from another class

Tags: c#

I've been working on a timer in c# just to mess around since I've never done it before.  I wanted to have the OnTimedEvents method I was declaring in a separate class as I will be calling it in various other classes for various other tests, but I cannot invoke it properly without getting errors.  Specifically, I am getting No Overload Method for Method '' Takes 0 Arguments.  I cannot work around this as I have with other methods.  This is the code:

```
class MSOfficeApps {
    public static Timer aTimer;

    public void appWord() {
        var programCS = new Program();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordObj;
        WordObj = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
        for(int i = 0; i < WordObj.Windows.Count; i++) {
            object idx = i + 1;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Window WinObj = WordObj.Windows.get_Item(ref idx);
            Console.WriteLine(WinObj.Document.FullName);
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(600000);  //Sets timer to 6 minute increments
            aTimer.Elapsed += ElapsedEventHandler(programCS.OnTimedEvent());  //Throwing an error at programCS.OnTimedEvent()
        }
    }
```

And this is what I'm trying to call

```
class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        SearchProcesses sP = new SearchProcesses();

        sP.BuildProcessLists();

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit the program...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
    }
}
```

Please advise :)

Comment: Advice: descriptively share errors (after reading them closely, thinking about what they mean, and searching).

Comment: Just a guess, but I think you want `MSOfficeApp` and `appWord` to both be static.

Comment: I added the error I keep running into.  Static doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
aTimer.Elapsed += ElapsedEventHandler(programCS.OnTimedEvent());
```

to

```
aTimer.Elapsed += ElapsedEventHandler(programCS.OnTimedEvent);
```

You are invoking programCS.OnTimedEvent, rather than passing it as a reference (and invoking it without arguments), thus the error.

Comment: I'm smacking myself, this was it.  ElapsedEventHandler is throwing an error ('type' but is used like a 'variable') but I can fix that on my own.  Thank you David!

Comment: No worries. However if you in future provide all the error details in your question people will be able to help you faster and you're less likely to get down voted or see close votes appearing :)